# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Tags: python-2.7

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(m):
    cid = m.chat.id
    secret = id_generator()
    hashedpw = hashlib.md5( secret ).hexdigest()
    cur.execute("INSERT into `users` (username, password) VALUES (str(cid), str(hashedpw)")
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "Your secret token is " + secret)
```

Can someone may help me in fixing this problem?
To be honest I have no idea what the problem could be.

Comment: Which tutorial are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have an error in your SQL syntax

You're missing a closing parenthesis `)` for `VALUES`:

```
cur.execute("INSERT into `users` (username, password) VALUES (str(cid), str(hashedpw))")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you need to pass the actual parameters to the database, which would be quoted for strings - e.g.

```
cur.execute("INSERT into `users` (username, password) VALUES ('jon','passwd')")
```

Try something like, which will use the values in your variables:

```
cur.execute("INSERT into `users` (username, password) VALUES (?,?)", (str(cid), str(hashedpw)) )
```

this answer may help:

[How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)